# Bash / Awk. Where do i put the IF-statement?

Tags: bash, unix, if-statement, awk, size

I'm in need of a bash script with awk to find files less than a certain size i.e 500KB and list these but can't seem to get an if-statement to work with this.

The following code outputs the files but all files and not the ones with a size less than said size.

```
#!/bin/sh
set `date`
ls -l -R |
awk "BEGIN { m = \"$2\"; d = $3 }
\$6 == m && \$7 == d && \$8 ~ /:/ {print}"
```

Where should I put the IF-Statement?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `find` for this:

```
find . -type f -size -500K
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. I have to use awk for this operation even though Find feels a lot easier.

Comment: @ssjohn When you say _"have to"_ - why? Parsing the results of `ls` is not something you should ever be doing. I'd strongly suggest changing the approach to whatever it is you're doing.

Comment: Part of an assignment I cannot fully grasp. ls isn't required but using awk is though. I've been searching for quite some while but can't seem to get it to work the way i've been trying.

Comment: If you wanted to be really cheeky you could just shell out...: `awk 'BEGIN { system("find . -type f -size -500k") }'` technically this uses awk...  :|

Comment: Finally got something to work with find and an awk pipe. Since all it said was that awk had to be in there somewhere. So now "find" finds the files and awk sorts them by size.
Thank you for your help! I was so into that ls should have been used instead of find.